# how do I make these the same height

Tags: css, text, vertical-alignment

The verses aren't the same height near the bottom and I want each verse side by side to be the same height. here's my code currently:

```css
.verse img {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>PSALM 1</h1>
<p>
  <div>
    <span class="verse" style="float:left; margin:auto; width:50%">
Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio imporium, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiae non sedit.<br><br>
sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte.<br><br>
Et erit tamquam lignum quod plantatum est secus decursus aquarum, quod fructum suum dabit in tempore suo: et folium ejus non defluet; et omnia quaecumque faciet prosperabuntur.<br><br>
Non sic impii, non sic; sed tamquam pulvis quem projicit ventus a facie terrae.<br><br>
Ideo non resurgent impii in judicio, neque peccatores in concilio justorum:<br><br>
quoniam novit Dominus viam justorum, et inter imporium peribit.</span>

    <span class="verse" style="float:right; position:inline-block; width:50%">
Blessed is he who does not walk in the counsel of the wicked, nor stand in the way of sinners, nor sit in the seat of scorners.<br><br>
But his delight is in the law of the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png">, and on His law he meditates day and night.<br><br>
He will be like a tree planted near good waters; he will bring good fruit in his season, and everything he does will prosper.<br><br>
Not so with the wicked! Not so... they are like chaff that the wind blows away.<br><br>
Therefore, the wicked will not stand in judgement, nor in the company of the just.<br><br>
For the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png"/> watches over the way of the just, but the way of the wicked leads to destruction.
</span>
  </div>
```

[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 0):

Many style and semantic issues here.

- `float` is a property to float an element within a text-block such as an image within a newspaper article. It is **not** a tool for designing purposes or aligning elements next to each other!
- `<br>` is a linebreak to move the next word/letter to the next line. It is **not** a tool to create spacings or for designing purposes. For that, you either have margins, padding, or gaps.
- a `<p>` is a paragraph that should be used for a single text block. It is schematically not correct o use a div within to include the text there and then break the text with `<br>`s. Multiple paragraphs for every single paragraph have to be used.
- You should not mix inline-style with external CSS.

### To the issue itself

A translation paragraph for paragraph IMHO is tabular data and as such a table should be used:

```css
.verse img {
  height: 1em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>PSALM 1</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio imporium, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiae non sedit.</td>
    <td>Blessed is he who does not walk in the counsel of the wicked, nor stand in the way of sinners, nor sit in the seat of scorners.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte.</td>
    <td>But his delight is in the law of the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png">, and on His law he meditates day and night.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Et erit tamquam lignum quod plantatum est secus decursus aquarum, quod fructum suum dabit in tempore suo: et folium ejus non defluet; et omnia quaecumque faciet prosperabuntur.</td>
    <td>He will be like a tree planted near good waters; he will bring good fruit in his season, and everything he does will prosper</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Non sic impii, non sic; sed tamquam pulvis quem projicit ventus a facie terrae.</td>
    <td>Not so with the wicked! Not so... they are like chaff that the wind blows away.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ideo non resurgent impii in judicio, neque peccatores in concilio justorum:</td>
    <td>Therefore, the wicked will not stand in judgement, nor in the company of the just.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>quoniam novit Dominus viam justorum, et inter imporium peribit.</td>
    <td>For the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png"/> watches over the way of the just, but the way of the wicked leads to destruction.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A visual alternative is the usage of CSS-Grid. However IMHO this would be semantically incorrect, especially for screen-readers:

```css
.verse img {
  height: 1em;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>PSALM 1</h1>
<section>
  <p data-lang="latin">
    Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio imporium, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiae non sedit.
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    Blessed is he who does not walk in the counsel of the wicked, nor stand in the way of sinners, nor sit in the seat of scorners.
  </p>
  
  <p data-lang="latin">
    sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte.
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    But his delight is in the law of the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png">, and on His law he meditates day and night.
  </p>
  
  <p data-lang="latin">
    Et erit tamquam lignum quod plantatum est secus decursus aquarum, quod fructum suum dabit in tempore suo: et folium ejus non defluet; 
    et omnia quaecumque faciet prosperabuntur.
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    He will be like a tree planted near good waters; he will bring good fruit in his season, and everything he does will prosper
  </p>
  
  <p data-lang="latin">
    Non sic impii, non sic; sed tamquam pulvis quem projicit ventus a facie terrae.
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    Not so with the wicked! Not so... they are like chaff that the wind blows away.
  </p>
  
  <p data-lang="latin">
    Ideo non resurgent impii in judicio, neque peccatores in concilio justorum:
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    Therefore, the wicked will not stand in judgement, nor in the company of the just.
  </p>
  
  <p data-lang="latin">
    quoniam novit Dominus viam justorum, et inter imporium peribit.
  </p>
  <p data-lang="english">
    For the <img src="/images/THE LORD.png"/> watches over the way of the just, but the way of the wicked leads to destruction.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you! this sort of works, but alternating latin and english verses in the source code doesn't work very well. (i want to be able to select more than one passage) ...

i would like for there to be a way to notate the whole latin text in the source code in a block, then the whole english text in a block

Comment: (is there a way to notate the tables "column-first", perhaps? that would be perfect)

Comment: do you know the amount of verses before?

Comment: yes (filler text to reach the minimum character requirement)